# How to Add a Data Bar in Every Other Cell within a Range of Cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a specific type of data bar I need in excel. I'm trying to apply this data bar to every other cell in a range of cells. It keeps applying it to all of my cell in my specific range instead of every other one. This is driving me crazy! Please help!

```
Sub ShadeEveryOtherRow()
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("N4:N120")
    Dim cell As Range

   'For every row in the current selection...
    For Counter = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        'If the row is an odd number (within the selection)...
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If Counter Mod 2 = 1 Then
                Call Add_Data_Bar(cell, cell.Value)
                End If
            Next cell
        Next Counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not add a image of your code - copy and paste it in your question

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this site and still trying to figure it out. @urdearboy

Comment: Looks like you have two loops when you probably only need one. What cells are selected when you run the code?

Comment: You can use Step 2 to skip every other row - you only need one loop for this though. For counter = start to end step 2 should suffice

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `step 2` for your counter. You also need `Counter` to be defined as an object for `Rows`. Hope this example helps:

```
Sub ShadeEveryOtherRow()
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("N4:N120")
    Dim cell As Range

   'For every row in the current selection...
    For Counter = 1 To rng.Rows.Count Step 2
        rng.Rows(Counter).FormatConditions.AddDatabar

    Next Counter
End Sub
```